# In angular js after reloading page it say error on server 404 can not found the page after using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I use 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); to remove # from url

http://seagullinteractive.com/#/about :-its work after reload
to
http://seagullinteractive.com/about :- its not work dont now the problem

Comment: The problem is there is no webpage called `/about` on server `http://seagullinteractive.com`.

Comment: Look at the below solution. Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create .htaccess file in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Need to put above rewrite rules. Then it will be fine. When you call http://seagullinteractive.com/about then your server will look for directory with name "about" which actually will not exist and you will get 404 as a result. You need to redirect to index.html(or whichever is your page that contains ng-app) if there is no resource found on server with requested URI.

Comment: thanks Ankit I get the result that I want the issue with my .htaccess file